# set hex color code "#ededed" as a background color of my mainscreen in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, background-color

I am working on a UI task in which i need to set the background color which is given in a hexcode "#ededed". Right now i m working with this code:

```
((VerticalFieldManager) getMainManager()).setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(**Color.LIGHTGRAY**));
```

but in place of this Color.LIGHTGRAY I have to use "#ededed" hex color code.

Please help me to come over this small but logical task.
Thanx in advance...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
((VerticalFieldManager) getMainManager()).setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xededed));
```

Comment: I think the string, "#ededed" needs to be converted to its integer equivalent on run time.

Comment: No need to do it at runtime, the compiler recognizes "0x" as a hex prefix, and interprets the following characters as a hexidecimal representation of an integer.

Comment: Great, it worked. Thanxx alot Eugen Martynov and the stack community.:)

Comment: @MichaelDonohue, I thought that the color code, "#ededed" was a String object.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is:

```
getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(0xededed));
```

No need to cast to a `VerticalFieldManager` since the main manager is a `Field` and that class contains the `setBackground` method.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use this link to convert colors to your desired color and implement in code

```
            http://easycalculation.com/color-coder.php
```

If you aim to use java color code this is the best link

```
            http://www.jafar.com/java/csel/index.html
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following code converts a String (hexadecimal representation) to its integer equivalent, and uses the value as background color.

```java
String strColor = "#ededed";
// remove # char
strColor = strColor.substring(1);

try {
    // get integer equivalent
    int iColor = Integer.parseInt(strColor, 16);
    getMainManager().setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(iColor));
} catch (Exception exc) {   
}
```